Is making a stator out of lamination of steel or iron like this that a CNC machine would cut through a block of laminated material?
I thought that building a stator for a BLDC motor using a pure metal like iron or steel would be enough, so that the stator would have been made from a pure material, but then I read that the eddy current would be increasing and the efficiency would be low in this case, so it has to be made from lamination of iron or steel. I want to know: is making a stator out of lamination of steel or iron like this that a CNC machine would cut through a block of laminated material, or is it more complex and the lamination would happen after cutting through the thin sheets of steel?

Don't see why not but for mass production I would guess it's quicker, cheaper and less wasteful to stamp the pieces out of flat sheets and then laminate them together.

The laminations have to be insulated from each other or they won't work to reduce eddy currents.
If you did machine a stack you might have to do something (grinding or fine sanding) at the machined surfaces to prevent shorts.
Commercially, motor laminations are stamped from pre-coated electrical steel supplied in roll form and stacked and cleated together by automated machinery.
Here is a video showing the whole process where incoming rolls of coated electrical steel are turned into finished stator lamination stacks in an automated process with a single operator supervising. Ready to go downstream to the winding machines.
Unlike E-I transformers, where the pre-wound bobbin is trapped between alternating lamination types, motor stators can be wound after the core is assembled.
In this video they recommend checking the die every week or 5,000,000 operations.
For smaller production runs there are techniques that incrementally notch the laminations etc. with a lot of labor involved, so unsuitable for high volume cost-sensitive applications.

Even if there's a generous burr shorting between laminations, it feels unlikely to be even a thou (in) wide; the resistance will be fairly high as a result. Perhaps with disruption of the oxide surface near the cut, the nearest some 10s of thou (0.25mm's) could become conductive, though still only with patchy contact. This will definitely increase losses, but not so much to cause malfunction I'd bet.

@TimWilliams You're probably right. They don't seem to do anything special to the punching (or perhaps they use the more sophisticated process of 'fine blanking') parts before assembly and sometimes weld them along one bead too.

Usually the laminations are stamped out of a roll of material, en masse. There's a press and the laminations fall out of it like slices of cheese from a cheese slicing machine. There's also the scrap metal with all the nice cutouts.
For smaller motors where the precision of stamped laminations may be insufficient, the laminations can be machined using EDM. They still are processed as a sheet or maybe a thin stack. Stacking is often more trouble than it's worth since laminations are mass-made, so the process must not involve any manual operations. Material goes into machine, laminations and scrap sheet comes out of the machine. Laser cutting can also be used for smaller volumes.
Things get hairy and expensive when you have to feed multiple continuous steel sheet rolls into a machine so that they can be squeezed together and processed as a stack. Maybe very high volume lines use that, but I've not seen it in person.

To make a stator out of a laminated steel sheet, would it be sufficient to cut the laminated sheet (bought from somewhere and we don't know how it is made) using the cutting machines in the shape of a stator? What I'm afraid is that maybe the laminated sheet of steel that is being sold is not the same as the ones used by manufacturers of motors and stators.

Cutting (mechanical) one sheet of this "electrical steel" is not equal to (mechanical) cutting of multiples of sheets. Each "leaf" of metal has non-conductive layer (silicon usually), to 'stop' magnetic flux and keep each metal sheet seperate (making a kind of small cage for "each" of eddy current). Yo  may try to cut multiple sheets by using EDM, but unsure how lenghty the process will be, and how precise it becomes.

@smajli non-conductive layer […] to 'stop' magnetic flux interesting.

@greybeard Simplification. There is not enough space to explain all in comment. Please check "Stacking factor" in wiki for example. Maybe I should be using 'keep seperated' instead of 'stop'

(@smajli or isolated - electrically, not magnetically.)

custom Lamination stacks for motor cores manufacturer has a overview of some manufacturing techniques used by a company which seems to specialise motor lamination stacks. I haven't been personally involved in such manufacturing but gives what looks like a reasonable overview.
Volume manufacturing
Compound stamping which uses a die to cut to shape:

Compound stamping is an essential production process used to manufacture motor lamination stacks. The process involves the simultaneous cutting and forming of sheet metal, which is then pressed into a desired shape to create a finished product such as motor cores.
The compound stamping process begins with an upper die containing a punch or other tool that cuts the metal piece from its flat form into a specific shape. Then, this cut piece is placed between two dies that work together to bend or form it into its final shape.

For stacking they have 3 options:


rivet : Riveting is usually suitable for low-voltage applications where high precision and accuracy are unnecessary. It involves using small metal pins to join two pieces of metal together at several points along their edges.
glue : Glue is often suitable for higher-voltage motors since it provides better insulation than rivets. The glue bonds the layers together while providing an airtight seal to prevent moisture or dust from entering the core.
welding : Welding involves layering individual steel laminations and welding them together, helping to create robust stators with high levels of electrical insulation.


Prototyping
For prototyping different techniques are used:

Laser cutting lamination to cut to shape.
Electrical discharge machining (EDM) to cut the laminates and weld them together in a permanent bond.

